# How can I prevent Jest from running async tests concurrently?

Tags: asynchronous, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm writing a series of tests against a database. All tests take the following form:

```js
test("Name", async ()=>{
    // I do not call done(). I didn't think I had to anymore,
    // and I get type errors if I do.
});
```

Unfortunately, this is causing concurrency issues. I'm not sure if that's down to background tasks on the DB, or Jest running tests concurrently. The tests work fine when run individually, so I know concurrency of some sort is the problem.

How can I make absolutely sure that Jest runs these async tests one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jest, the tests in a single file run serially in the order of appearance. However, the tests in multiple files run concurrently. This is a problem when you are running all the tests against a single database.

To disable running the tests in multiple files concurrently, use the CLI option [`--runInBand`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--runinband) in your `jest` command.

For example:

```
jest --runInBand
```

If you use scripts like `npm run test` to run your tests, then append the `--runInBand` to the associated command in `package.json` file.